# Remove loops from the code?

Tags: vectorization, matlab

Is it possible to remove all the loops from the following code and calculate `k` values using vectors.

```
index = 0;
for i = 1.1:0.1:2.5
    for j = 200:300:3000
        for z = 1:14:14000
            index = index + 1;
            k(index) = (log(i) *pi/(sqrt(j)))* exp(z);
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
[I, J, Z] = meshgrid(1.1 : 0.1 : 2.5, 200 : 300 : 3000, 1 : 14 : 14000);
k = log(I) .* pi ./ sqrt(J) .* exp(Z);
k = reshape(permute(k, [3 2 1]), 1, []);
```

ps: are you sure about the ranges? exp(14000) can not be calculated with regular precision.
and check this step `permute(k, [3 2 1])` - may be the order is not exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple `matrix multiplication` here and this must be fast and efficient as nothing beats matrix multiplication on `MATLAB` -

```
array1 = 1.1:0.1:2.5;
array2 = 200:300:3000;
array3 = 1:14:14000;

mult1 = (log(array1).')*(pi./(sqrt(array2))); %//'
mult2 = mult1(:)*exp(array3);
out = mult2(:).';
```